# How to combined two Select queries' outputs in to one JsonObject in a same php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have two select queries in my php.

```
$rr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sales_target WHERE rep = '502' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'"); 
$r=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tbl_sales.ton_ach/1000) AS tonSum, SUM(tbl_sales.val_ach/1000000) AS valSum FROM tbl_sales INNER JOIN tbl_mas_customer on tbl_sales.customer = tbl_mas_customer.customer WHERE rep = '502' AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'");
```

I want to combined each queries output in to one Json.
This is my Json output for both queries

```
{"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","col_tar":"69.92"}]}{"feed":[{"tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}
```

**What I want is something like this.**

```
{"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","col_tar":"69.92","tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}
```

This is my **php** script.

```
$r=mysql_query("select sum(tbl_sales.ton_ach/1000) as tonSum, sum(tbl_sales.val_ach/1000000) as valSum from tbl_sales inner join tbl_mas_customer on tbl_sales.customer = tbl_mas_customer.customer where rep = '502' and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'");

$rr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_sales_target where rep = '502' and DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'");     
    $result = array();
    $resultt = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rr)){
        array_push($result,
        array('rep'=>$row[0],           'date'=>$row[1],'val_tar'=>$row[2],'ton_tar'=>$row[3],'col_tar'=>$row[4]));}

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($resultt,
        array('tonSum'=>$row[0],
       'valSum'=>$row[1]));}

        $json['feed']= $result;
                echo json_encode($json);

        $jsonn['feed']= $resultt;
                echo json_encode($jsonn);
```

**My tables**
[image]

**Edited**

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT  tbl_sales_target.*,
        SUM(tbl_sales.ton_ach/1000) AS tonSum, 
        SUM(tbl_sales.val_ach/1000000) AS valSum 
FROM tbl_sales_target 
JOIN tbl_mas_customer ON tbl_mas_customer.rep = tbl_sales_target.rep
JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_sales.customer = tbl_mas_customer.customer
WHERE tbl_sales_target.rep = '502' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'");

    $result = array();

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,
        array('rep'=>$row[0],
       'date'=>$row[1],'val_tar'=>$row[2],'ton_tar'=>$row[3],'col_tar'=>$row[4],'tonSum'=>$row[5],'valSum'=>$row[6]));}

        $json['feed']= $result;
                echo json_encode($json);
enter code here
```

**output**

```
 {"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","c‌​ol_tar":"69.92"},{"tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}
```

**what i want**

```
{"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","c‌​ol_tar":"69.92","tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}
```

**Android method**

```
 private void getJsonRequest(final Button a, final Button b, final Button c) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
        final String systemDate = df.format(new Date());

        final SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cr = sqLiteHandler.getData(sqLiteHandler);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        do {
            repNo = cr.getString(0);
        } while (cr.moveToNext());
        cr.close();

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REP_SUMMERY, hashMap, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("feed")) {
                        productSummList = parseJsonResponse(response);

                        txtTarget.setText(productSummList.get(0).getTar_ton() + " MT");
                        double tar_ton = Double.parseDouble(productSummList.get(0).getTar_ton());
                        int intTar_ton = (int) tar_ton;
                        arcProgress.setMax(intTar_ton);

                        arcProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(Color.GREEN);
                        arcProgress.setStrokeWidth(20f);
                        arcProgress.setBottomTextSize(35f);
                        arcProgress.setBottomText("Ton");
                        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(arcProgress, "progress", 0, 30); // see this max value coming back here, we animale towards that value
                        animation.setDuration(1500); //in milliseconds
                        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                        animation.start();

                        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                txtTarget.setText(productSummList.get(0).getTar_ton() + " MT");
                                arcProgress.setBottomText("Ton");
                                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(arcProgress, "progress", 0, 30);
                                animation.setDuration(1500);
                                animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                                animation.start();
                            }
                        });

                        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                txtTarget.setText(productSummList.get(0).getTar_col() + " Mil");
                                arcProgress.setBottomText("Collection");
                            }
                        });

                        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                txtTarget.setText(productSummList.get(0).getTar_val() + " Mil");
                                arcProgress.setBottomText("Value");
                            }
                        });
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "System Date " + systemDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Date " + productSummList.get(0).getTar_ton(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Log.d("Database Date ", productSummList.toString());

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                productSummList = parseJsonResponse(response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("rep_no", repNo);
                hashMap.put("systemDate", systemDate);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }



private ArrayList<ProductSummery> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<ProductSummery> productSumList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {

            try {

                JSONArray arrayProduct = response.getJSONArray(KEY_FEED_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayProduct.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = arrayProduct.getJSONObject(i);
                    String repName = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_ID);
                    String date = currentObject.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String valTar = currentObject.getString(KEY_VALUE_TARGET);
                    String tonTar = currentObject.getString(KEY_TON_TARGET);
                    String colTar = currentObject.getString(KEY_COL_TARGET);

                    ProductSummery productSummery = new ProductSummery();
                    productSummery.setRepNo(repName);
                    productSummery.setDate(date);
                    productSummery.setTar_val(valTar);
                    productSummery.setTar_ton(tonTar);
                    productSummery.setTar_col(colTar);

                    productSumList.add(productSummery);

                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productSumList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return productSumList;
    }
```

**New PhP script...........**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

 require_once 'include/Config.php';

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("connection failed");
    mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE) or die("db selection failed");


    $r=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  tbl_sales_target.*,
        SUM(tbl_sales.ton_ach/1000) AS tonSum, 
        SUM(tbl_sales.val_ach/1000000) AS valSum 
FROM tbl_sales_target 
JOIN tbl_mas_customer ON tbl_mas_customer.rep = tbl_sales_target.rep
JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_sales.customer = tbl_mas_customer.customer
WHERE tbl_sales_target.rep = '502' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'");


    $result = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,array('rep'=>$row[0],'date'=>$row[1],'val_tar'=>$row[2],'ton_tar'=>$row[3],'col_tar'=>$row[4],'tonSum'=>$row[5],'valSum'=>$row[6]));}


        $json['feed']= $result;
                echo json_encode($json);


    mysqli_close($con); 


?>
```

**This is the error**

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ceat_sap\rep_summery_test.php on line 32
{"feed":[]}
```

Comment: can you please post the sample. data of `tbl_sales` and `tbl_mas_customer`. you need to use joins with 1st query

Comment: also why dont you just simply select columns with 2nd query? rather than 2 queries.

Comment: it didn't work. I tried to use inner join for three tables . It didn't work..

[My tables][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zJTB6.jpg

Comment: why `table_sales_target` has no relation ? where is `foreign key` and `primary key` relation ?

Comment: table_sales_target has no primary key. values are duplicating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it i think

```
$feed = array("feed" => array_merge($result, $resultt));
echo json_encode($feed);
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Another way would be to simply merge the 2 queries into 1.

```
SELECT  tbl_sales_target.*,
        SUM(tbl_sales.ton_ach/1000) AS tonSum, 
        SUM(tbl_sales.val_ach/1000000) AS valSum 
FROM tbl_sales_target 
JOIN tbl_mas_customer ON tbl_mas_customer.rep = tbl_sales_target.rep
JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_sales.customer = tbl_mas_customer.customer
WHERE tbl_sales_target.rep = '502' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(tbl_sales.date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'
AND DATE_FORMAT(tbl_sales_target.date, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'
```

Comment: it is not working... This error come...

**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ceat_sap\rep_summery_test.php on line 31
{"feed":[]}**

Comment: for the first answer it is actually give an output, but it not in one json as i mentioned. It gives me something like this  

{"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","col_tar":"69.92"**},{**"tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}

I don't need },{ in between the two json

Comment: Nog sure what you have done with the query, it should work. Also with the first answer i'm pretty sure it should work. Are you sure you echo'ed json_encode($feed)? Maybe add the code so i can see what you did.

Comment: I updated it.... First one is worked.But what I want the json without  **},{**
between "69.92" and "tonSum" ...

Comment: i understand, but there is no way the array_merge function would leave a comma between them. could you send the code where you are using the first solution?

I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong on the second solution

Comment: I am using it in Android.. I want to access to valSum and tonSum values. If it is comming from one JsonObject I can.But i don't know to extract the values from the output of the first solution. I will update the android code

Comment: i don't think i needed the android code.
join chat if you want to discuss this somewhat easier:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107729/room-for-d-madushanka

Comment: combining the queries is the cleanest solution, apparently something is still going wrong in the query and that is why it returns false, Turn on your error reporting to get a better idea of what that is.

put this at the start if your php before you execute the queries:

error_reporting(-1);

Comment: I updated my answer.still give me errors. I need to find the solution from the second one.combining two queries. but i can't find the error. can you see the tables and see you can find a problem? I updated the new php script and error.

Comment: Can you add the following after the mysql_query (so after $r is set) and tell me what it says:

if (!$r) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    exit();
}

Comment: I have found the solution friend. That happen because both table has date filed and need to clearly mention what table date should take.. simple put **tbl_sales_target.date** to where clause. thank you for show me a path

Comment: hey, do you konw a way to access valSum and tonSum in this JsonArray

{"feed":[{"rep":"502","date":"2016-03-01","val_tar":"64.91","ton_tar":"84.59","c‌​ol_tar":"69.92"},{"tonSum":"45.201940","valSum":"33.150250"}]}

Comment: you should probably add both dates so you don't select the wrong data, see edited answer. and to access those you first json_decode the string if you haven't yet and then: $result['feed'][1]['tonSum'] and $result['feed'][1]['valSum']